# QWebview not loading

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt project, I have an initialized `QWebView` and I create it, load a url, and then show it. This used to work a while ago, but now it just has stopped loading.

Relevant Code:

```
void MainWindow::activateWebView()
{
    webview = new QWebView();
    QUrl link("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=724514964748-43gb17l2laj7mg3vcj2qpfe7o6fn4ceu.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&response_type=code&access_type=offline");
    connect(webview, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(webViewloadFinished(bool)));
    webview->setWindowTitle("Connecting to Google...");
    connect(webview, SIGNAL(titleChanged(QString)), webview, SLOT(setWindowTitle(QString)));

    webview->setMinimumSize(600, 700);
    webview->setMaximumSize(600, 700);
    webview->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    webview->show();
    webview->load(link);
}
```

Comment: What is your Qt version?

Comment: @AlexisP. Currently, I'm using Qt Version 5.5

Comment: You may want to try `QWebEngineView` instead of `QWebView` because Qt WebKit is deprecated. Also, you can read more about it [here](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html)

Comment: @AlexisP. It says module 'webenginewidgets' not found.

Comment: Did you install it ? Check with Qt maintenance tool

Comment: @AlexisP. just looking. I can't use webenginewidgets because it is only supported through MSVC 2013. I have MinGW.

Comment: Oh... Ok, two quick questions : 1/ Did the slot named `setWindowTitle` use to work? 2/ Did you try to do `load(link)` before `show()`?

Comment: @AlexisP. I tried both of those. `setWindowTitle` just sets it to 'website' and I tried loading the link at different times but to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. From the last successful build to the latest unsuccessful build I had re-installed my OS. This apparently caused issues with some SSL dlls. I was missing three files in my MinGW

- libssl32.dll
- ibeay32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

I found these files in the installation of [OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL-1_0_2g.exe). I added these files into my MinGW bin folder and it now is working!